# How to cancel a FastReport print job?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

How do I show a MessageBox when a print job is canceled in FastReport's Print Job Dialog?

Comment: Hi, user.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  I cleaned up your question a little bit, but I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "show a messagebox if canceling a print job."  Do you mean "show a dialog box for the user to use to cancel the print job" or "detect whether the user has canceled the print job, and if so, show a message box"?

Comment: Are you looking for:   if not frxReport1.Print then Showmessage('Aborted');

Comment: Usually biggest trouble is not reporting engine but underlaying datasources. Long running queries returning thousands of rows.

Comment: Why do it more difficult then it has to be :) Thanks a lot ...Was trying with whnd and other solutions but I did not know that this simple solution was working.... Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

When frxReportPrint.Print returns false, it is either user cancel or error in printing. So you need to check Errors.Text is empty or not, like:

```
if not frxReportPrint.Print then
  if frxReportPrint.Errors.Text = '' then
    UserCancel := true
  else
    Abort; // something wrong during printing.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if frxReport1.Print then Showmessage('Aborted');
```

Comment: frxReport1.Print returns true means printing is ok, not canceled.