# FastReport VCL5 > How to recognize cancellation of PDF export?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, fastreport

I am using C++ Builder XE4 and FastReport VCL 5.

I am trying to recognize the cancellation of PDF Export.
The code is as follows.

```
PDFGraphForm->frxReport1->Export(PDFGraphForm->frxPDFExport1);
```

For the recognition of the cancellation of `frxReport1->Print()`, I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941760/how-to-cancel-a-fastreport-print-job).
However this does not apply to `frxReport1->Export()`.

I tried using `bool res = frxReport1->Export()` and clicked cancel button on the Export dialog. However, the res variable was always true.

Any other way to recognize the cancellation of the Export()?

Answer (score 0):

Just use OnBeginExport event of frxPDFExport1 control.
Tested just seconds ago, it won't fire up unless report is actually exported.

Regards

Comment: I am testing with 10 pages' report including Windows sample Image for each page. At the frxReport1->Export(), the dialog showing "Exporting page X" is shown with Cancel button. It seems that the OnBeginExport event is fired before the dialog is shown. So, even I click the cancel button on the dialog, the cancellation cannot be recognized.

Comment: I am thinking to use "frxPDFExport1->ShowProgress = false" and show my own Progress Form with cancel button instead.

Comment: So Your Raport contains 10 pages and You'd like to cancel in the middle of the process right ? For frxPDFExport whole report is like single entity, so when You start it, OnBeginExport is indeed fired up on first page. In this case You can use tfrxReport Events

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my poor explanation. I will check tfrxReport events. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: This answer is wrong, -1. The OnBeginExport even is fired when the export is started, and before it is possible to know whether it will be cancelled (predicting the future is still not possible).

Comment: Has anyone solved this? I'm also looking for an answer.